# Saving an ID value from an API to a User with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, graphql-mutation

I'm working on a video game website where a user can save a game to a list. How this is supposed to work is when the user clicks "Complete Game", the ID of the game is saved to a state that holds the value. The value is then passed into the mutation, then the mutation runs, saving the ID of the game to the users list of completed games. However, all I'm seeing in the console is this:

```
"GraphQLError: Variable \"$addGame\" got invalid value { gameId: 740, name: \"Halo: Combat Evolved\",
```

The above error continues, listing the entirety of the API response, instead of *just* the gameId.

I was able to successfully add the game to the list in the explorer with the following mutation:

```
    mutation completeGame($addGame: AddNewGame!) {
        completeGame(addGame: $addGame) {
            _id
            completedGameCount
            completedGames {
                gameId
            }
        }
    }
```

with the following variable:

```
{
  "addGame": {"gameId": 740}
}
```

How can I trim down what is being passed into the mutation to just be the gameId?

Below is the entirety of the page, except the return statement at the bottom.

```
    const [selectedGame, setSelectedGame] = useState([]);

    const [savedGameIds, setSavedGameIds] = useState(getSavedGameIds());

    const [completeGame, { error }] = useMutation(COMPLETE_GAME);

    const { id: gameId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => saveGameIds(savedGameIds);
    });

    useEffect(() => {

        async function getGameId(gameId) {

            const response = await getSpecificGame(gameId);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong...');
            }

            const result = await response.json();

            const gameData = result.map((game) => ({

                gameId: game.id,
                name: game.name,
                cover: game.cover,
                summary: game.summary,
                platforms: game.platforms,
                platformId: game.platforms,
                genres: game.genres,
                genreId: game.genres,
                
            }));

            setSelectedGame(gameData);

        }

        getGameId(gameId);

    }, [])

    const handleCompleteGame = async (gameId) => {
        
        const gameToComplete = selectedGame.find((game) => game.gameId === gameId);

        const token = Auth.loggedIn() ? Auth.getToken() : null;

        if (!token) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            const { data } = await completeGame({
                variables: { addGame: { ...gameToComplete } },
            });

            console.log(data);

            setSavedGameIds([...savedGameIds, gameToComplete]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

    };
```

With the mutation working in the explorer when I'm able to explicitly define the variable, I am led to believe that the issue is not with the resolver or the typedef, so I'm going to omit those from this post because I don't want it to get too long.

However, I'd be happy to attach any extra code (resolver, typeDef, getSavedGameIds function, etc) if it would allow anyone to assist. The issue (I think) lies in getting my response to match the syntax I used in the explorer, which means trimming down everything except the gameId.

I specifically am extremely suspicious of this line

```
const gameToComplete = selectedGame.find((game) => game.gameId === gameId)
```

but I have fiddled around with that for awhile to no avail.

Thank you to anyone who is able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to pass more into your mutation then your schema is defined to allow. In this part:

```js
const { data } = await completeGame({
  variables: { addGame: { ...gameToComplete } },
});
```

You're spreading `gameToComplete` here which means everything in the `gameToComplete` object is going to be sent as a variable. If your schema is setup to just expect `gameId` to be passed in, but your error message is showing that `name` is also being passed in, you just need to adjust your variables to exclude everything you can't accept. Try:

```js
const { data } = await completeGame({
  variables: { addGame: { gameId } },
});
```